# 'set' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, django

I am creating a movie web app, with Python and Django, and it has a search function it that gives me some error I don't really understand.

ERROR

```
[16/May/2016 16:22:05] ERROR [django.request:284] Internal Server Error: /movies/search/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\git\DjangoServer\movies\views.py", line 157, in search
set(filteredresolution)
  File "C:\Users\user\git\DjangoServer\movies\views.py", line 38, in list
request.session['nextpage'] = reverse('movies:list', kwargs={'page': page})
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'session'
```

movies/views.py search function

```
def search(request, keyword='', resolution='all'):
    if request.POST:
        request.session['nextpage'] = reverse('movies:search', kwargs={
            'keyword': request.POST.get('keyword'),
            'resolution': request.POST.get('resolution')})
    else:
        request.session['nextpage'] = reverse('movies:search', kwargs={
            'keyword': keyword,
            'resolution': resolution})

    searchresult = []
    resolutions = Resolution.objects.all().order_by('name')

    if request.POST:
        keyword = request.POST.get('keyword')
        resolutionid = request.POST.get('resolution')
    else:
        keyword = keyword
        resolutionid = resolution

    filteredkeyword = []
    filteredresolution = []
    filteredall = Movie.objects.all()

    if keyword != '':
        filteredkeyword = Movie.objects.filter(title_en__icontains=keyword)
    else:
        filteredkeyword = filteredall

    if resolutionid != 'all':
        storedmovies = StoredMovie.objects.filter(resolution__id=int(resolutionid))
        for stored in storedmovies:
            filteredresolution.append(stored.movie)
    else:
        filteredresolution = filteredall

    searchresult = list(
        set(filteredkeyword) &
        set(filteredresolution)
    )

    return render(request, 'movies/search.html', {
        'movies': searchresult,
        'lang': lang,
        'countresult': len(searchresult) #ez mire is?
    })
```

I kind-of understand that the error is where I create the segment of the 2 list, but there is no session there.
I call it from the list page that is the following:

```
def list(request, page=1):
    request.session['nextpage'] = reverse('movies:list', kwargs={'page': page})

    lang = request.session.get('language', 'failed')
    if lang == 'failed' or lang not in supported_langs :
        return redirect('movies:language')

    movie_list = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-added')
    resolutions = Resolution.objects.all().order_by('name')
    paginator = Paginator(movie_list, 20) # Show 20 contacts per page

    #page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        movies = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        movies = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        movies = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'movies/list.html', {
        'movies': movies,
        'lang': lang,
        'resolutions': resolutions,
        })
```

Comment: when you do `searchresult = list( set(...) & ...)` do you mean to use the builtin `list` function or your own one?

Comment: I meant to use the built in one, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having a view called `list`, you are *shadowing the built-in `list`*. Rename your view.